# I am not able to get the metrics from Linear Regression in R for the test dataset

Tags: r, regression

I built the linear regression model. I have train and test the dataset. Train dataset has 9970 observations and the test dataset has 10000 observations. The total variable in the training dataset is 9 and the target variable is "Earnings". My test dataset doesn't have Earnings, hence I need to predict it.

My code as follows

```
lr_fit <- lm(Earnings~., data = data)
training_predictions <- predict(lr_fit, newdata = data)
R2(training_predictions, data$Earnings)
```

The above code is working and I can able to calculate the R2

I am predicting the test dataset

```
testing_predictions <- predict(lr_fit, newdata = test)
R2(testing_predictions, test$Earnings)
```

I can able to predict, however, I am not getting the R-Square. Getting below message

[image]

I am not able to solve this error. Please advise

Comment: What is `class(test$Earnings)` ?

Comment: @BastienDucreux It is coming "NULL"

Comment: Then the problem comes from there, `test$Earnings` should be a numeric vector, you will have to check the `test` data and properly import it